# Get wkhtmltopdf to use high resolution image from srcset

Tags: html, webkit, wkhtmltopdf, qtwebkit

I'm using `wkhtmltopdf` to translate a webpage to a PDF document, but some of the images in the result file are a bit low resolution.

The source webpage actually has the `srcset` attribute used to provide higher resolution versions for higher pixel density displays.  However `wkhtmltopdf` doesn't appear to be using them.

I figured as this is a WebKit based tool, and WebKit definitely supports this attribute, there might be something I could set to make WebKit use the highest resolution version available.

**Edit**: While I'm waiting on figuring out a better way of doing this, I have managed to successfully preprocess the HTML with `xmlstarlet`, by stripping all but the last URL out of the srcset, renaming the attribute src, and removing the last but one src attribute (the HTML is generated so all images follow an identical format in their usage of src / srcset).

```
xmlstarlet ed -P \
  --update "//img/@srcset" \
    -x "substring-before(substring-after(.,', '),' ')" \
  --rename "//img/@srcset" -v "src" \
  --delete "//img/@src[position()=last()-1]" file.html
```

A useful workaround until I find a more elegant solution!

Comment: Hi, same issue, some years after ^^ The problem is that `xmlstarlet` seems very sensitive to the HTML validity, and it cries over badly structured pages (even using `unesc` to clean the file). No solution there, for the moment I just use the low quality images :/